Solve $2^x − 5^y = 39$
The problem
The number of pairs $(x, y)$ of natural numbers, which are solutions of the equation $2^x − 5^y = 39$ is...?
my idea
The first thing I thought of was the the last digit.
We know that the last digit of $5^y$ is $5$ so the last digit of $2^x$ must be $4$, which means $x$ divided by $4$ has rest $2$ so $x$ has the form $4k+2$.
I also thought of using modular arithmetic, but I don't know how.
If it helps, I know that the answer is that their is only one pair of $(x,y)$.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

$2^x-5^y$ is not a polynomial. Please, use the tags carefully.

The first step toward a solution is realizing that the exponents $x,y$ are both even. OP finds this for $x$, and other answers find this for $y$ by analyzing the equation $\bmod 3$. Noting that $2^x>39$, I found $y$ is even by analyzing the equation $\bmod 8$
So the task is to find pairs of squares that differ by $39$. Other answers try to describe conditions on the exponents of $2$ and $5$ to solve the problem. In this case there is an easier approach. The number of ways a given number $n$ can be expressed as the difference of squares is equal to the number of divisors $d$ of $n$ such that $d<\sqrt{n}$ and $d\equiv \frac{n}{d} \bmod 2$. For a full discussion of this, see my answer to this problem. The analysis is based on the fact that any square $k^2$ is the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers.
The divisors of $39$ are $1,3,13,39$, of which $1,3$ meet the criteria. This tells us that there are exactly two ways to express $39$ as the difference of two squares. For $d=1$, we obtain the case that $39$ is the sum of $1$ odd number whose average value is $\frac{39}{1}=39$. Knowing that the $i$th prime is equal to $2i-1$, we conclude that $39$ is equal to the sum of the first $20$ odd numbers minus the sum of the first $19$ odd numbers. Thus we expect that $39=20^2-19^2=400-361$ which is true. However, $400,361$ do not have the form $2^x,5^y$ so this is not a solution to the question.
For $d=3$, we obtain the case that $39$ is the sum of $3$ consecutive odd numbers whose average value is $\frac{39}{3}=13$. That series is $11,13,15$. $15$ is the $8$th odd number, and the series to be subtracted ends in $9$, which is the $5$th odd number. Thus we expect that $39=8^2-5^2=64-25$ which is true. In this case, $64,25$ do have the form $2^x,5^y$ so this is a solution to the question.
Now we know we are done. We do not have to further analyze exponents in complicated forms to look for and rule out other possibilities, because we know that there are exactly two ways to express $39$ as the difference of two squares and we have exhausted those two possibilities, only one of which meets the conditions of the question.

Hint By working modulo $10$ you've in particular shown that $2^x$ must be a square, namely, $(2^{2 k + 1})^2$. What about modulo $3$?

Reducing modulo $3$ shows that $y$ must be even, say, $y = 2 l$, hence we have a factorization $$39 = 2^x - 5^y = (2^{2 k + 1})^2 - (5^l)^2 = (2^{2 k + 1} - 5^l) (2^{2 k + 1} + 5^l)$$ into integers. Can you take it from here?


How did you got that y must be even. All I got that y must be congruent with 1 modulo 4

Reducing modulo $4$ gives no information about $y$.

Modulo $3$ does work though; since $x$ is even, $2^x = 4^z$ and therefore $2^x \equiv 1 \mod 3$. Then $5^y \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and therefore $y$ is even

@PamMunozRyan I don't know how you got $y$ must be 1 modulo 4, but that's false.

@MikeDaas Why does the fact that $5^y$ is 1 modulo 3 make y even?

@PamMunozRyan orders/induction, if $y$ is odd, then $5^y\equiv2$ mod 3

@Lucenaposition Okkk...thanks...so from here we take some cases: if the first pharantese is 39 and the second 1, and the following other pairs (13,3),(3,13),(1,39), right? Is there any need to also check the negative ones?

$2^{2k+1}+5^l$ must be positive

The second factor is larger than the first, so there are really only $2$ cases to check: $(1, 39)$, $(3, 13)$. One leads to one solution, the other to a contradiction.

Modular arithmetic is useful here, and there are a few natural choices for what to quotient by.  Namely, we want things that will make at least one of the terms vanish.  We first note that there are no solutions with $x=0$ or with $y=0$, and so if we work mod 2, then $2^x$ vanishes, and if we work mod 5, then $5^y$ vanishes.  Further, if we work modulo 3 or 13, then the 39 vanishes.  Mod 2 or 4 end up not being useful, and 13 is a bit too large to give quick insights.
Mod 3, the equation becomes $(-1)^x\equiv (-1)^y\pmod{3}$, which forces $x$ and $y$ to either both be even or both be odd.  Reducing mod 5 we get $2^x\equiv -1\pmod 5$, which forces $x\equiv 2\pmod 4$.  In particular, we know that $x$ and $y$ are both even.  This sets up $39$ as a difference of squares.  Set $x=4k+2, y=2\ell$.  Then
$$39=(2^{2k+1})^2-(5^{\ell})^2=(2^{2k+1}-5^{\ell})(2^{2k+1}+5^{\ell}).$$
Since $39$ only factors into positive integers as $1\cdot 39$ and $3\cdot 13$, this gives us two possible systems of equations to solve
$$\begin{cases}2^{2k+1}-5^{\ell}=1 \\ 2^{2k+1}+5^{\ell}=39 \end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}2^{2k+1}-5^{\ell}=3 \\ 2^{2k+1}+5^{\ell}=13 \end{cases}$$
In each case, we can solve directly for $2^{2k+1}$ and $5^{\ell}$, and then check whether they are actually powers of 2 and 5 respectively or not.

You might as well add that the former system does not give a solution, but the latter does in fact yield $2^6 - 5^2 = 39$

In a question like this, you can expect a pattern that doesn’t apply with small numbers, so you take out your calculator to check y from 0 to say 5 and find 5^2 + 39 =64 64.
For larger y, 2^x ≈ 5^y, so x log 2 ≈ y log 5. You use Euclid’s algorithm to find pairs x, y so that x log 2 - y log 5 becomes smaller and smaller. The difference must become smaller the larger x and y become, and if you check values that make the difference small you find it never will be small enough.
Euclid’s algorithm makes x, y candidates grow exponentially fast, so you can check say 100 digit numbers easily.
